# How to prove that det(A+tH) is non-zero?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, determinant

The question is as follows:

$A\in GL(n,\mathbf{R}):=\{T \in \mathbf{R}^{n*n}: \det(T) \neq 0\}$

Fix $H \in \mathbf{R}^{n*n}$ and prove that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\det(A+tH) \neq 0,\forall t \in (-\delta, \delta)$.

I am unsure of how to approach this question, as I do not see how to relate the determinant of $H$ and $A$ to the determinant of the sum of them.

I also do not understand intuitively why a $\delta$ should exist for any $H$.

I would write what I have tried, but I really do not know where to begin.

Comment: Since $\det(A+tH)=\det(A)\det(I+tA^{-1}H)$, it suffices to consider the case where $A=I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is false then there exists a sequence  $t_n \to 0$ such that $det(A+t_nH)=0$ for all $n$. Determinant is a continuous function of the matrix entries so we get $det (A)=0$ in the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider $|A+tH|$, this is a polynomial about $t$ where it's degree is $n$.

So$|A+tH|=0$ has finite roots.

You can choose  a suitable  $\delta$, $\forall ~t\in (-\delta,\delta)$,$|A+tH|\ne 0$.